# Simplified expression of $ _2F_1((K-1)a,K,Ka,x) $

Tags: special-functions, closed-form, hypergeometric-function

Is there any simplified expression of this Hypergeometric function $ _2F_1((K-1)a,K,Ka,x) $

Thanks!